# How can i Limit My Wp Theme To Only One Site

Tags: theme-development

i created my first wp theme and i want to use it alone, i wouldn't like any other person(wp site) to be able to use it even though they got it by chance,

Please is there a way i can put some sort of feature whereby the wp theme will not work when the user has not activated it...

Comment: If somehow someone got your theme files, they will be able to use it. You could use some db trick if you want to make it a little difficult to use. For example, check the value of a table cell on theme activation, and if it doesn't has the expected value, don't activate the theme

Comment: Wow, this is very more technical than i.

Comment: How would somebody get your theme without you giving it to them? It’s not possible to download themes from websites without FTP access.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, a theme's files is only available to someone with FTP or File Manager (via your hosting's cPanel) access. If you don't give your theme files to anyone, they are all your own.

As long as you keep your FTP access secure, your theme's files will be secure.